# Regexp: finding multiple matches for a single asterisked group

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

Suppose we have `/(a*b)*/` regexp, and we would like to get

```
{"aab", "ab", "aaab"}
```

as a set of matches for the only pair of parenthesis (group) when matching with `"aababaaab"` string. Sure we could [modify this regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246773/javascript-regex-finding-multiple-parentheses-matches)  with `g` modifier, and run it in a loop, but there're a lot of more complicated examples, when such rewrite is unsuitable due to code blowup. .NET has such an interface called a [capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Is there any way to do the same in JS either using standard library or external libraries?

Comment: Can you add a "more complicated" example to your question ?

Comment: @Alex `/((a*b)* )*/` -> `/(a*b)*/g` + match/shift in loop -> `/a*b/g`+ 2 x match/shift in two loops. Real world example was parsing `clist.by`  contents in Google Script (regexps was "ultima ratio" due to absence of built-in XPath implementation and buggy HTML parser). Won't add these to the question, as it would only complicate it, and as almost everyone had such problems himself.

Comment: You should provide a better explaination. As far as I can understand, the following code should match your requirements (why loops?) : `'aababaaab'.match(/a*b/g)`.

Comment: The question is about an implementation of regex for JS with capture groups, not this exact example you thought was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but if you want to get the minimun expressión of your query you can use a ungreedy match:

```
'aababaaab'.match(/(a*b)+?/g);
```

The problem of this is that you will not get all the combinations, but you seem not care about that in your question.

Comment: Read the question once more, please. I know that one can use `g` modifier to achieve this.